# How do I enable scrollbar for vertical scroll and disable for horizontal?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scrollbar, singlechildscrollview

I've been building layout with both horizontal and vertical scrolling. Vertical scrollable `Column` is for main content and is populated by different views, including horizontal `ListView` which shows promo banners. I wanted to show scrollbar for vertical scrolling, but not for horizontal. I've wrapped the `SingleChildScrollView` which makes `Column` scrollable in `ScrollBar`, but the bar appeared on both vertical on horizontal scrolls. Is there any fine-tuning for these kinds of things?

**Sample to demonstrate the issure**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scrollables',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            HorizontalListView(),
            VerticalListView(),
          ]),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalListView extends StatelessWidget {
  var items = new List<String>();

  _addNewItem(int index) {
    items.add("Item $index");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
      height: 120,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 15,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(child: ListItem(index));
          }));
}

class VerticalListView extends StatelessWidget {
  var items = new List<String>();

  _addNewItem(int index) {
    items.add("Item $index");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: 50,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListItem(index);
          }));
}

class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  int _index;
  ListItem(this._index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 280,
      child: Text("Item ${this._index}"),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Scrolling demonstration]

*Pay attention to the bottom on horizontal scrolling*

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I didn't, sadly. Still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class NoScrollbar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const NoScrollbar({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (_) => true,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Just wrap the NoScrollbar Widget around the Scrolling Widget, you don't want to have the Scrollbar appear. This solved it for me!

Comment: I don't understand how this works but it does work

Comment: @MobileMon flutter scrollbar is based on `ScrollNotification`s, and because returning `true` from the `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` `onNotification` will prevent notication bubbling, it won't reach the `Scrollbar` widget and it thus it won't appear

Answer (score 1):

Niklas answer did not work for me in Flutter 2.5. I don't know if it's because my layout is different or what. But if you have a PageView (as a carousel for example) inside a ListView the way I found to remove PageView's scrollbar is the following.

Add to `Scrollbar` widget a `notificationPredicate`:

```dart
notificationPredicate: (ScrollNotification notification) {
  return notification.depth == 0 && notification.metrics.axis == Axis.vertical;
}
```

This will only show scrollbar for vertical interactions.

Flutter documentation about [notificationPredicate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar/notificationPredicate.html).