# Hide scrollbar while scrolling is still enabled in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, singlechildscrollview

I'm using a `SingleChildScrollView`. I want to enable scrolling but hide the scrollbar.
In Android I used `android:scrollbars="none"` to accomplish this but cannot seem to find a way to do this in Flutter.
All existing questions remotely related to this topic talk about how to disable scrolling not merely hiding the scrollbar.
Is there a way to accomplish this or is there a way to reposition the scrollbar to better position the scrollbar in my app?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753569/8618880) solved it for me

Comment: scrollbar does not show in `SingleChildScrollView`, it shows if you manually wrap it up with `Scrollbar` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the top of your widget tree and Add [ScrollConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html) widget above it

```
ScrollConfiguration(
    behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
```